# Python - Conversão de QDate para datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt-5

Preciso converter uma data entrada por um QCalendar para datetime (da lib datetime). Como posso fazê-lo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O **QDateTime** tem uma função **toPyDateTime** que retorna um objeto **datetime** padrão

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QDateTime

#usando Date
QDate.currentDate().toPyDate()
datetime.date(2017, 3, 17)

#usando DateTime
QDateTime.currentDateTime().toPyDateTime()
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 17, 19, 9, 45, 974000)
```

Comment: Certo, tentei isso e retornou essa exceção:  Except: 'QDate' object has no attribute 'toPyDateTime'

Comment: Você está usando o PyQt5 ou o PySide?

Comment: Estou usando o PyQt5!

Comment: Vi que no seu erro vc usa o QDate junto com o toPyDateTime mas na verdade ele so suporto toPyDate. Da uma olhada no código acima que editei